# warning when signing apk with cordova

Tags: cordova, apk, signing

i want to sign my unsigned.apk with cordova but i am getting warning.
Warning:
The signer's certificate is self-signed.

I have my unsigned.apk in apk/release folder.

```
  :\Users\PC\Test1\platforms\android\app\build\outputs                            
    \apk\release>jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1                         -keystore PudziBreak.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk pudzibreak
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
 updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/PUDZIBRE.SF
   adding: META-INF/PUDZIBRE.RSA
  signing: AndroidManifest.xml
  signing: assets/www/SHOWG.TTF
  signing: assets/www/cordova-js-src/android/nativeapiprovider.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova-js-src/android/promptbasednativeapi.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova-js-src/platform.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova-js-src/plugin/android/app.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova.js
  signing: assets/www/cordova_plugins.js
  signing: assets/www/css/index.css
  signing: assets/www/game.js
  signing: assets/www/img/BrickLeftHitToUse.png
  signing: assets/www/img/BrickLeftNoHitToUse.png
  signing: assets/www/img/BrickRightHitToUse.png
  signing: assets/www/img/BrickRightNoHitToUse.png
  signing: assets/www/img/Combo.png
  signing: assets/www/img/HeroMain5.png
  signing: assets/www/img/LeftBrick.png
  signing: assets/www/img/LeftBrickDestroyed.png
  signing: assets/www/img/Mute.png
  signing: assets/www/img/RightBrick.png
  signing: assets/www/img/RightBrickDestroyed.png
  signing: assets/www/img/Timer.png
  signing: assets/www/img/UnMute.png
  signing: assets/www/img/background8.png
  signing: assets/www/img/bars2.png
  signing: assets/www/img/bird.png
  signing: assets/www/img/clock.png
  signing: assets/www/img/czasteczka.png
  signing: assets/www/img/doors2.png
  signing: assets/www/img/flyingBrick.png
  signing: assets/www/img/forest.png
  signing: assets/www/img/how2play.png
  signing: assets/www/img/lifter5.png
  signing: assets/www/img/menu.png
  signing: assets/www/img/playButton.png
  signing: assets/www/img/sky2.png
  signing: assets/www/img/star.png
  signing: assets/www/img/street7.png
  signing: assets/www/img/warning.png
  signing: assets/www/index.html
  signing: assets/www/js/index.js
  signing: assets/www/phaser.min.js
  signing: assets/www/sounds/bodySound.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/hit1.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/hit3.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/hit4.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/hit5.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/hit6.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/playsound.mp3
  signing: assets/www/sounds/theme.mp3
  signing: classes.dex
  signing: res/drawable-land-hdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-land-ldpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-land-mdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-land-xhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-land-xxhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-hdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-ldpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-mdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-xhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-xxhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-v4/screen.png
  signing: res/mipmap-hdpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-hdpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-hdpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/mipmap-ldpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-ldpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-ldpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-ldpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/mipmap-mdpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-mdpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-mdpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xhdpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-xhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
  signing: res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_background.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v26/ic_launcher_foreground.png
  signing: res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
  signing: res/xml/config.xml
  signing: resources.arsc
>>> Signer
    X.509, CN=Patryk Murawski, OU=pip, O=pip, L=Kadzidlo, ST=Tatarska, C=07-420
    [trusted certificate]

jar signed.

Warning:
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
```

Please i need help.  in release folder i have unsigned.apk , output.json, keystore old and keystore.Im not sure if there was jarsigner and i have deleted it. Was it there?

Comment: how are you taking the release build? CLI or Android Studio?

Comment: I think CLI, because im not using android studio

Comment: did you try with Studio? It helps to do all the heavy lifting for you, compared to the build.json file

Comment: I have tried but im getting error that my page cant be loaded, file:///android_asset/myHtml.html because net::ERR_FILENOT_FOUND

Comment: Please help i want to publish it :D

Comment: Can you try using android studio? Its easier and recommended if you arent an experienced person with cordova.

Comment: I tried  but im getting error that my page cant be loaded, file:///android_asset/myHtml.html because net::ERR_FILENOT_FOUND     , which i cant repair